# Custom email macro

Tags: macros, hyperref, email

I'd like to define an email macro that does the following:

Input: `\domainemail{Jack Johnson}`

Output: Jack Johnson

The output should be a highlighted hyperlink that reads "mailto:jack.johnson@domain.org".

What I have is

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=DarkBlue]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\domainemail}[1]{\href{mailto:#1@domain.org}{#1}}
```

which produces the link "mailto:Jack Johnson@domain.org"

How can I replace the space with a period and upper- with lowercase initials? I tried enclosing `#1` with `\lowercase` but that seems to break the hyperlink.

### Bonus

Extra points if `\domainemail` can handle umlauts (including ß) and multiple first and last names, e.g.

Input: `\domainemail{Johnson-Löffler, Jack Björn}`

Output: Johnson-Löffler, Jack Björn with hyperlink "mailto:jackbjoern.johnson-loeffler@domain.org"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parts of the code are based on another answer of mine. With `\addtranslations` you set up the “translation” you wish for the Unicode characters you need. Anyway, for very strange names, you can use the optional argument to `\domainemail`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtranslations}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_casimir_search_replace_seq { ##1 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\domainemail}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \casimir_domainemail:n { #2 }
   }
   {
    \casimir_href:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_casimir_search_replace_seq
\tl_new:N \l_casimir_input_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_lower_case:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \casimir_href:nn { \href{mailto:#1@domain.org}{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \casimir_href:nn { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \casimir_domainemail:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__casimir_domainemail_temp_seq { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__casimir_domainemail_temp_seq > 1 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_casimir_input_tl
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \l__casimir_domainemail_temp_seq { 2 }
      .
      \seq_item:Nn \l__casimir_domainemail_temp_seq { 1 }
     }
    \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_casimir_input_tl { ~ }
   }
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__casimir_domainemail_temp_seq { ~ } { #1 }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_casimir_input_tl
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l__casimir_domainemail_temp_seq { . }
     }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_casimir_input_tl { \tl_lower_case:V \l_casimir_input_tl }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_casimir_search_replace_seq
   {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_casimir_input_tl ##1
   }
  \casimir_href:Vn \l_casimir_input_tl { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% set up the translations

\addtranslations{
  {æ}{ae},
  {ä}{ae},
  {ö}{oe},
  {ü}{ue},
  {ß}{ss},
  {ñ}{n},
  {é}{e},
}



\begin{document}

\domainemail{Jack Johnson}

\domainemail{Johnson-Löffler, Jack Björn}

\domainemail{Äöß, Reñé Joseph}

\domainemail[strange]{Some strange name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Adding the period is simple with `\add@period#1 #2{#1.#2}` using space as a delimiter of the first and the second name, typing it with a `.` then.

Transferring the names into lower case is more difficult, in my point of view, but I used `\text_lowercase:n` from `expl3` which provides this facility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=DarkBlue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}

\makeatletter
\def\add@period#1 #2{#1.#2}%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\addperiod}[1]{%
  \text_lowercase:n{\add@period#1}% Expandable lower case
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\newcommand{\domainemail}[1]{%
  \href{mailto:\addperiod{#1}@domain.org}{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\domainemail{Jack Johnson}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A screen shot is difficult here....

Comment: @Rmano: No, you are right: I forgot to remove it from a temporary solution (or a trial of a solution ;-)). Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Might I alert you to my bonus question in case you're interested in tackling that as well?

Comment: @Casimir: No, because you changed the question which is not how TeX.SE works

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of it before.